# Matrix function minimzation

Tags: matlab

If I wanted to minimize the function `f(x,y)=(abs(x+y)-abs(x)-abs(y))` squared, subject to a bunch of linear constraints, where `x` and `y` are real vectors or real arrays.

There are two problems:
- The function is not exactly convex (though certain linear cuts through it are), meaning that algorithms that use differentiation to minimize maybe won't work.
- The function to minimize does not return a real scalar, and the most common algorithms for maximization (at least in MATLAB with fmincon and fminsearch) require the objective function to return scalars.

Is there a way I can solve this cleanly numerically using whatever technology?

Comment: How do you define the minimum of a non-scalar function?

Comment: I was thinking about substituting the absolute values with norms, then the function would return a scalar.

Comment: No, I mean if your function returns a non-scalar value, and you want to find its minimum, you must have some idea about what a minimum of a non-scalar value is? You cannot sort vectors or matrices like that. For example, what is smaller, the vector [3,4] or the vector [4,3]? This is the reason that algorithms for minimization/maximization expect functions that return a scalar. Anything else doesn't make sense.